# Setting lua table in redis

Tags: json, lua, redis

I have a lua script, which simplified is like this:

```
local item = {};
local id = redis.call("INCR", "counter");
item["id"] = id;
item["data"] = KEYS[1]
redis.call("SET", "item:" .. id, cjson.encode(item));
return cjson.encode(item);
```

`KEYS[1]` is a stringified json object:

`JSON.stringify({name : 'some name'});`

What happens is that because I'm using `cjson.encode` to add the item to the set, it seems to be getting stringified twice, so the result is:

`{"id":20,"data":"{\"name\":\"some name\"}"}`

Is there a better way to be handling this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, regardless your question, you're using `KEYS` the wrong way and your script isn't written according to the guidelines. You should **not** generate key names in your script (i.e. call `SET` with `"item:" .. id` as a keyname) but rather use the `KEYS` input array to declare any keys involved a priori.

Secondly, instead of passing the stringified string with `KEYS`, use the `ARGV` input array.

Thirdly, you can do `item["data"] = json.decode(ARGV[1])` to avoid the double encoding.

Lastly, perhaps you should learn about Redis' Hash data type - it may be more suitable to your needs.

Comment: Ah, hm, so how would you suggest "building" the key's if they are based off the response of `INCR`.  I could see doing INCR first, then using it in the lua script, but if the lua fails, then I would have gaps in ids, which I'd prefer not to have, would like it to all be one atomic operation.

Comment: Do the INCR, then call the Lua - it's simple and works. Better not treat IDs as continuous sequences - this assumption rarely survives the real world. Re "atomicity", your current script suffers from the same potential problem (i.e. it could fail [although I'm unsure why you think it will] after the `INCR` and before the `SET`).